# Pass a value to the ftp.retrbinary callback

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm writing a module that uses FTPLib to fetch files. I want to find a way to pass a value(in addition to the block) to the callback.  Essentially, my callback is

```
 def handleDownload(block, fileToWrite):
    fileToWrite.write(block)
```

And I need to call

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR somefile', handleDownload)
```

And have it pass a file handle. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can close over the `fileToWrite` variable with a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
fileToWrite = open("somefile", "wb")
ftp.retrbinary("RETR somefile", lambda block: handleDownload(block, fileToWrite))
```

Comment: Is there any other way to download the file other than saying 'write'? I want to be able to retain the timestamp given on the FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
class File:

    cleared = False

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath

    def write(self,block): 
        if not File.cleared:
            with open(f'{self.filepath}', 'wb') as f:
                File.cleared = True
                with open(f'{self.filepath}', 'ab') as f:
                f.write(block)
        else:
             with open(f'{self.filepath}', 'ab') as f:
                 f.write(block)

ftp.retrbinary("RETR somefile", File(filepath).write)
```

Comment: the code should work, however You could have just made it into one function not make a whole class

Comment: one function will allow you to add only last binary block.

Comment: to be fair I don't even remember commenting here, so I forgot what was my thought, so ... carry on, have a nice day